# Insert dynamic menus to electron menu bar app

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, electron

I'm new to electron and I'm trying to create a Mac only menu bar app that has dynamic menu items in it. My idea is when clicking 'add...' it adds/appends/inserts a new menu item in it.

My code appends the new item into the menu array. However I can't make it render the 'updated menu'.

```
const { resolve } = require('path');
const { app, Tray, Menu } = require('electron');

const iconPath = resolve(__dirname, 'assets','iconTemplate.png');

let contextMenu;
let tray = null;
let menu;

app.on('ready', function() {
  tray = new Tray(iconPath);
  menu = [
    {
      label: 'Add...',
      click: function() {
        // add new item between 'Add...' and 'Quit'. New one always on top of the last.
        menu.push({label: 'new item'});
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Quit',
      enabled: false
    }
  ]
  contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menu);
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I figured out myself.

```
let counter = 0; // Start counter globally
```

```
// add new item between 'Add...' and 'Quit'. New one always on top of the last.
  menu.splice(1, 0, {label: String(counter)});
  render(); // Call render for every alteration on the menu array
  counter++;
```

```
function render() {
  contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menu);
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
}
```